# Join table in mySQL return me NULL if joined table don't contain row

Tags: mysql, join

Here my tables structure:

___Rooms

```
|--------|-------------|
| ROO_Id | ROO_HotelId |
|--------|-------------|
|      1 |      ABC123 |
|      2 |      ABC123 |
|      3 |      ABC123 |
|--------|-------------|
```

___Subscriptions

```
|-------------|-----------|
| SUB_HotelId | SUB_Limit |
|-------------|-----------|
|      ABC123 |        19 |
|      XYZ987 |        23 |
|-------------|-----------|
```

This query work when `___Rooms` has a rows with desired `HotelId`.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(ROO_Id) AS SUB_RoomNumber, 
    SUB_Limit 
FROM ___Subscriptions 
LEFT JOIN ___Rooms 
    ON ___Rooms.ROO_HotelId = ___Subscriptions.SUB_HotelId 
WHERE SUB_HotelId = 'ABC123'
    AND ROO_HotelId = 'ABC123'

|----------------|-----------|
| SUB_RoomNumber | SUB_Limit |
|----------------|-----------|
|              3 |        19 |
|----------------|-----------|
```

For hotel `XYZ987`, this hotel do not have actually room in `___Rooms`, and the query return me NULL for `SUB_Limit` :

```
|----------------|-----------|
| SUB_RoomNumber | SUB_Limit |
|----------------|-----------|
|              0 |      NULL |
|----------------|-----------|
```

Why please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not check for `ROO_HotelId = 'XYZ987'`, inside the **Where** condition. If there is no matching `ROO_HotelId` in the `__Rooms` table, no data would appear (if using Where).

Basically, once you have done Join between the tables, ON HotelId, you only need to put Where condition for one of the tables. In the case of Inner Join, either of the tables can be used. However, in the case of Left join, you need to use the left table.

Use the following:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(ROO_Id) AS SUB_RoomNumber, 
    SUB_Limit 
FROM ___Subscriptions 
LEFT JOIN ___Rooms 
    ON ___Rooms.ROO_HotelId = ___Subscriptions.SUB_HotelId 
WHERE SUB_HotelId = 'XYZ987'
```